# Prevent all component rendering

Tags: reactjs

I have a variable that stores components, for example:

```
const list = {
   components: [<ComponentOne key={1}/>, <ComponentTwo key={2}/>]
}
```

Only the component that the customer chooses will be rendered, the other component not chosen should be stand by, but it cannot be destroyed, because when the customer chooses the other one, it should appear but not be rebuilt all over again.

But when I switch from ComponentOne to ComponentTwo and then go back to ComponentOne, it is rebuilt and I lose everything that has already been done in ComponentOne

Is there a way that when the created component is not rendered, it does not lose all its state?

Comment: When you conditionally render components, they will unmount and mount by default. You can hide the components using css `visibility: hidden` based on the condition maybe

Comment: You can also manage the internal state of your list of components in the parent and pass down as props.

Answer (score 2):

I can see two options to achieve what you want:

1. Manage the state outside of the components
2. Render all the components but only display the current one

### 1. Manage the state outside of the components

All he components part of the list would be stateless (no useState nor this.state defined) and their state would be managed outside and passed down as props.

This can be done having the state in the parent component, or in a react context.

```js
const [ state, setState ] = useState()
const list = {
   components: [ComponentOne, ComponentTwo]
}
const CurrentComponent = list.components[index]

return <CurrentComponent state={state} setState={setState} />
```

#### 2. Render all the components but only display the current one

This isn't the most idiomatic way to do it in react but should work in most cases. Your components would have a css property with `display: none` except of the currently displayed one which would have `display: block` (alternatively visibility: visible/hidden).

Comment: thanks for answering
I still don't understand it very well (I'm a beginner in react)

for example,
inside each Component there is an input, how do I control the value of each input separately using your example?
I am creating the components in a react context
I tried to do it here, but when I change the component, the input is the same value as the other component

Comment: You probably need the two components to use a distinct state. For example having two useState() instead of one and passing down the right state to the right component.